# NSData to Type converts to wrong enum

Tags: swift

I've got this definition:

```
struct DataPacket {
    struct Header {
        enum PackageType: UInt8 {
            case some2        =  0x02
            case intermediate =  0x03
            case error        =  0x04
            case some5        =  0x05
        }

        let firstByte: UInt8
        let secondByte: UInt8
        let status: PackageType
    }

    let header: Header
}
```

Why does this:

```
    let data = Data(bytes: [0xff, 0xfe, 0x03, 0x56, 0x53]) as NSData
    let packet = data.bytes.load(as: DataPacket.self)
    print(packet.header.firstByte)
    print(packet.header.secondByte)
    print(packet.header.status)
```

print this:

```
    255
    254
    some5
```

instead of this:

```
    255
    254
    intermediate
```

Maybe it's just a brainfart from my side...?

Comment: I don't know why but if you change `0x03` to `0x00` in your `data`, then `status` becomes `some2`. Change it to `0x01` and `status` is `intermediate`, etc. It seems that byte value is being interpreted as an offset, not the expected case value.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah. It's strange. So basically if I add all values up before 0x02 I'll get correct...

Comment: Note that you probably shouldn't rely on this behaviour; well at least not until ABI stability, that is. The memory layout of types is still subject to change up until then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift enums are indeed stored as offsets, a value of 0x03 always means "the fourth case" and not "the case where rawValue == 0x03".

https://academy.realm.io/posts/goto-mike-ash-exploring-swift-memory-layout/ has a section on this:

> What’s going on here is the raw value can be stored off in a separate table somewhere, the compiler knows about it, there’s no per-instance raw value of any kind, so it can just be zero, one, two, three, four. Somewhere else there’s a table that says zero is “whatever”, one is B, two is C, and so forth.